# How do I override window.screen?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm writing a simple PhantomJS app that scrapes particular pages looking for patterns. In one of these pages, the owner of the site is reading the `window.screen` width/height properties and changing the URL on me (which is cancelling the loading of the rest of the page). Setting the `viewportSize` changes the width/height values of the window, but not of the `screen` object.

### Attempt 1

My first step was disabling navigation, like so:

```
tab.onLoadStarted = function () {
    tab.navigationLocked = true;
};
```

However, because this check is done in the `<head>`, it is causing the `load` event to fire, and sometimes the page hasn't fully loaded yet (which is causing lots of other issues).

### Attempt 2

I tried overriding the screen object at the first load:

```
tab.onLoadStarted = function () {
    tab.evaluate(function () {
        window.screen = {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080
            };
    });
};
```

However, that property is read-only, so setting it does nothing to change the value.

### tl;dr

**In PhantomJS, is there a way to override the `window.screen` value to set my own screen size?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the `window.screen` values in the `LoadStarted` event, but you can in the `Intialized` event. So, instead, the code would look like this:

```
tab.onInitialized = function () {
    tab.evaluate(function () {
        window.screen = {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080
            };
    });
};
```

Comment: How should this be used in a CasperJS script? When I insert this code in the beginning, the script ends with no error message and does nothing.