# How can I change window.screen dimensions in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is it possible to change the screen dimensions as reported by screen.availWidth and screen.availHeight in PhantomJS 2.x? Although it is possible to specify the *window* size, it seems that the *screen* dimensions are always reported as 1024x768.

Note: although the solution for [How do I override window.screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045727/how-do-i-override-window-screen) works, I find it somewhat hacky and was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I don't see how that solution is hacky, can you clarify?  It's executing code inside a phantomjs event function.  Many libraries have event life cycles to handle this sort of execution.

Comment: I don't mind implementing life cycle methods, it's just that manually overwriting (monkeypatching) properties of a standard javascript object does not feel good. I would have expected that PhantomJS would have some other way of specifying properties of the environment at startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java, it can be done like this:

driver =  new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));